# simulink discrete 0 and 1 function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am running the model in external mode in real time hardware with discrete fixed step solver. I need to  generate an input signal to my hardware as boolean  0 and 1 with sample time 0.01.

1.Is there any block to generate 0 and 1 as input signal in simulink. 
2.Also another doubt, with input start for 2second as 1 and 5 second as 0 and another desired (as user desired time it can give input as 1 or 0 )

Kindly suggest me.

Comment: You are almost looking for a [pulse generator](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pulsegenerator.html), but it does not allow you to change its properties in real-time based on user input.

Comment: Please format your post, it makes it much easier to read. To create a numbered list, you need a space before the number and after the `.`, or you can use the specific icon to create a numbered list.

Comment: @m7913d: ya pulse generator doesn't work in real time discrete solver in Simulink. Is there any other discrete block to generate boolean o and 1